# Pandas: How can I update dataframe values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two spreadsheets where one is updating the other.

How can I update this data using the `pandas` library?

Example, where 'b' updates 'a':

```
a = {'field': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'value': ["", None, 1]}
b = {'field': ['a', 'b', 'd'], 'value': [1, 2, 1]}
```

Expected outcome:

```
c = {'field': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'value': [1, 2, 1, 1]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df_a = pandas.DataFrame(a)

df_b = pandas.DataFrame(b)

c = pandas.concat([df_a, df_b], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(subset=['field'], keep='last')
```

Comment: thanx!! Very good your solution.
I learned with it

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way of resolving it. 

`x = a['field']
y = b['field']
c = {}
c['field'] = set(x+y)`

I'm not sure what result you are looking for the 'value' key. It is eliminating 'None' values and empty values as "" and it is get all the values present both lists. Is that right?

Comment: how i do it in pandas?

Comment: Use pandas.concat([a, b], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()

Comment: I try it. but not work, how i need.
This code discarts all updates from second dataframe.
:/

Comment: Okay try this one!